# Proper dockerfile for ansible which runs on k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, dockerfile

I have aks cluster and I create a pod for ansible from basic image like nginx and install everything from shell manually by shell commands(pip3 install ansible, pip3 install openshift). Now I need to create an ansible image with necessary updates, here is my dockerfile. It works fine on laptop, but when I push repo and create a pod it backoff error. Maybe someone help me to understand how I can deploy correct image for ansible. Thanks

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04. 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
python3.5 \
python3-pip \
python3-setuptools \
curl \
sudo \
nano \
&& \
apt-get clean && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install ansible
RUN pip3 install openshift
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s 
https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN chmod +x ./kubectl
RUN sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

and here is ansible_pod.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ansible
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: ansible-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: ansible-data
  containers:
    - name: ansible
      image: ansible:latest
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /scripts
          name: ansible-data
      restartPolicy: Never

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ansible-data
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
     storage: 1Gi
```

Comment: `kubectl describe` will give you some details.

Comment: thanks @code_ada but it is only saying it is crashbackoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> create a pod it backoff error.

That's because you have your `CMD` as `bash`, but (a) bash expects to be able to read from stdin if not provided with a command, and your `PodSpec` does permit that (b) even if it did, what do you expect the container to **do**? Just sit there until someone runs `kubectl exec` in order to run arbitrary ansible playbook commands?

I would guess the shortest path to a non-backoff error would be to ask your already created docker image to just sleep indefinitely, until someone does `kubectl exec` into the pod and/or you come up with what you expect the pod to **do**

```yaml
  containers:
    - name: ansible
      image: ansible:latest
      command: ["sleep", "infinity"]
```

---

While this isn't what you asked, you seem to be spending a lot of energy to install python into a generic image, instead of using a [`docker.io/library/python:3.5` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) that comes with python already installed and merely needs the rest of those binaries laid on top of it

Comment: Thank you so much @mdaniel this solved my problem already. Now I have a pod without crashing and maybe in future I will change my image with your suggestion.